# Numpy - row-wise normalization

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've been working on a matrix normalization problem, stated as:

Given a matrix M, normalize its elements such that each element is divided with the corresponding column sum if element is not 0.

```
cwsums = np.sum(class_matrix,axis=1)
cwsums = np.reciprocal(cwsums.astype(np.float32))
cwsums[cwsums == np.inf] = 0
## this is the problem
final_matrix = np.multiply(final_matrix, cwsums)
```

I can construct a reciprocal mask, which I would like to apply accross the matrix, as an elementwise product, yet I can't seem to get it right. Thank you!

Comment: `EDIT: what I have written seems to work, but it is slow` check again, it seems to be row-wise broadcast, not columnwise.

Comment: You are correct, I re-edited, thanks!

Comment: So, you want to normalise across columns, correct? You will need axis=1, which is right. Also, my code works for me. What is the shape of your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Addressing edited question) Looks like you meant to sum across rows using `axis=0`:

```
i = 1 / class_matrix.sum(axis=0)
i[~np.isfinite(i)] = 0

class_matrix *= i
```